# ActiveAdmin doesn't work on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm currently trying to get ActiveAdmin to work on a model of mine but always get the error:

```
NoMethodError in Admin/hotel_rooms#index

Showing /home/maxp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activeadmin-0.4.3/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: render renderer_for(:index)
```

And I'm kinda clueless why this is happening. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table in the database didn't have an ID as primary key.